# Conditional Validation in ZF2

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework2

I have a form which starts with a Select with two options. There are several other fields, some of which are required for the first Select option, and the others required for the second Select option.

In the view, I'm using the Select to show/hide the relevant/irrelevant fields. Most of these fields are required when their option in the Select is selected.

What is the best way to only validate the fields that are relevant to whatever is selected in the Select?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you could do something like that (the key is the form's **setValidationGroup** function):

```
//GET THE FORM
$form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get( '<FORM_NAME>' );

//GET THE POSTED DATA
$request = $this->getRequest();
$data = get_object_vars( $request->getPost() );

//DEPENDING ON THE SELECT VALUE, VALIDATE THIS OR THAT FIELDS
if ( $data[ 'SELECT_NAME' ] === 'A' ) {
    $form->setValidationGroup( array( 'INPUT_A', 'INPUT_B' ) );
} else {
    $form->setValidationGroup( array( 'INPUT_C', 'INPUT_D' ) );
}

//PERFORM THE FORM VALIDATION
if ( !$form->isValid() ) {
    //FORM IS WRONG
    ( ... )
}

//FORM IS OK
( ... )
```